# Setting up Google weather extended forecast with classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic

Just a little background, our marketing department has been using static weather images on their signage and asked if it would be possible to pull something that updated in realtime. Since I'm the only person in our department with any type of programming experience, and I'm a novice at best, I got asked to come up with a solution. I have worked with classic asp in the past for a couple of other small projects I've done, so I decided to go that route. I have everything working the way I want it to with the exception of the extended forecast data. In the sample below I have the variables that I want to display with a For statement to pull the extended forecast xml data for each day. But for some reason it is only pulling the the last day of the extended forecast.

```
If (objXMLDOM.parseError.errorCode <> 0) Then
Response.Write("<p>Error parsing XML: " & objXMLDOM.parseError.reason & "</p>")
Else
  For i = 0 to 3  
    Set objFuture = objXMLDOM.getElementsByTagName("forecast_conditions").Item(i) 'pull the XML node for each from one to three
    For Each xmlNode In objFuture.childNodes 'loop through the dom tree
        If (xmlNode.nodeName = "icon") Then
            strIcon1 = "<img src=""http://www.google.com" & xmlNode.Attributes.getNamedItem("data").text & """ border=""0"">" & vbCrLf
         End If
        If (xmlNode.nodeName = "condition") Then
            strCondition1 = xmlNode.Attributes.getNamedItem("data").text & vbCrLf
         End If
        If (xmlNode.nodeName = "low") Then
            strLow = xmlNode.Attributes.getNamedItem("data").text & vbCrLf
         End If 
        If (xmlNode.nodeName = "high") Then
            strHigh = xmlNode.Attributes.getNamedItem("data").text & vbCrLf
         End If     
        If (xmlNode.nodeName = "day_of_week") Then
            strDay = xmlNode.Attributes.getNamedItem("data").text & vbCrLf
         End If     
     Set objFuture = nothing    
    Next    
Next
End if
```

I am then outputing the 4 day forecast into my main page with the following code:

```
<%For Each Item in objXMLDOM.getElementsByTagName("forecast_conditions")
  Response.Write ("<td>" & strDay  & "<br>" & strIcon1 & "<br>" & strCondition1   & "<br>" & "Low:&nbsp" & strLow & "&deg;F" & "<br>" & "High:&nbsp" & strHigh & "&deg;F" & "<br>" & "</td>")
 Next %>
```

I have been looking at this off and on for a couple of days now and just can't seem to find what I am missing to pull each day instead of the just the last one. If anyone has any suggestions I would appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the same set of variables to store the forecast data for each day.  So during every iteration of your `for` loop you are overwriting the previous day's information.

The solution is to move the code that writes the data to the screen insideyour first `for` loop, like such:

```
If (objXMLDOM.parseError.errorCode <> 0) Then
    Response.Write("<p>Error parsing XML: " & objXMLDOM.parseError.reason & "</p>")
Else
    For i = 0 to 3  
        Set objFuture = objXMLDOM.getElementsByTagName("forecast_conditions").Item(i) 
        For Each xmlNode In objFuture.childNodes

            ...

        Next 

        ' Write to the page here
        Response.Write ("<td>" & strDay  & "<br>" & strIcon1 & "<br>" & strCondition1   & "<br>" & "Low:&nbsp" & strLow & "&deg;F" & "<br>" & "High:&nbsp" & strHigh & "&deg;F" & "<br>" & "</td>")

    Next
End if
```